# How to make CSS animation not affecting other HTML in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, css-transitions

I'm making a project called Random Quote Machine using React. And try to do some animation transition when state in React Component it's being updated. But I don't want the animation transition to affect all of the content.

Before getting into the problem, this is my code:

CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bitter:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap');

// Font Variable
$main-fonts: 'Bitter', serif;

// Color variable
$default-color: #d1d1d1;
$white-color: #ffffff;
$black-color: #000000;

// Animation Fade-In transition
@mixin animation($time){ 
  animation: fadeIn $time;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn $time;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn $time;
  -o-animation: fadeIn $time;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn $time;
}

// Start of evert keyframes //
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
// End of keyframes //

// Classes to add to React when state updated for it's element performed the animation
.animation-transition {
  @include animation(2.5s);
}

// HTML LAYOUT //
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: $white-color;
  font-family: $main-fonts;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
 
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.quote-box {
    background: $white-color;
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 2rem 3rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    
    .quote {
      color: $black-color;
      padding: 0rem 1.6rem;
      
      
      .quote-text {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
      }
      
      .quote-icon {
        width: 35px;
        margin-bottom: -8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
  }
  
    .quote-author {
      color: $black-color;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 1.5rem 0rem;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
  
    .buttons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 0.45rem;
    
      & > * {
          background-color: $black-color;
          color: $white-color;
          height: 38px;
          border-radius: 3px;
          font-weight: 400;
          padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .tweet-quote-button {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
      }
      
      .new-quote-button {
        font-size: 0.85rem;
      }
      
      .tweet-quote-button:hover, .new-quote-button:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
   }
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  
  span a {
    color: $white-color;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

React code:

```
// START OF App Parent Component //
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      quote: "",
      author: "",
      color: "",
      fade: false
    }
    
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.animationStart = this.animationStart.bind(this);
  }
  
  /* RANDOMLY GET VALUE FROM QUOTE OBJECT and color arrays to store as state value */
  getData() {
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
    const q = QUOTE[n]['quote'];
    const a = QUOTE[n]['author'];
    const c = colors[n];
    
    this.setState({
      quote: q,
      author: a,
      color: c
    });  
  }
  
  /* TRIGGERED WHEN USER CLICK BUTTON TO SET STATE TRUE OR FALSE OF TRANSITION ANIMATION */
  animationStart() {
    this.setState({
      fade: true
    })
    
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("false called");
      this.setState({
        fade: false
      })  
    }, 2400);
  }
  
  /* TRIGGER WHEN USER CLICK NEW QUOTE BUTTON, GET NEW VALUE FOR STATE TO RENDERED */
  handleClick() {
    this.getData();
    this.animationStart();
  }
  
  /* THIS WILL HANDLE STATE TO PASS TO CHILD IN VERY FIRST RENDER */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.animationStart();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <QuoteBox quote={this.state.quote} author={this.state.author} color={this.state.color} fade={this.state.fade} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
// END OF PARENT COMPONENT //

// START OF QUOTE BOX CHILD COMPONENT //
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    {/* GET QUOTE-LEFT ICON FROM CODEPEN ASSETS*/}
    const iconQuote = <svg class="quote-icon" viewBox="0 0 512 512" title="quote-left">
  <path d="M464 256h-80v-64c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64h8c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-8c-88.4 0-160 71.6-160 160v240c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h128c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V304c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-288 0H96v-64c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64h8c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V56c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24h-8C71.6 32 0 103.6 0 192v240c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h128c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V304c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48z" />
</svg>
      
    {/* CHANGE THE BACKGROUND OF HTML BODY AFTER RENDER*/}
    {/*document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.props.color;
    
    if (this.props.fade) {
      document.body.classList.add('animation-transition');
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('animation-transition');
    }*/}
    
    return (
      <div style={{'backgroundColor': this.props.color}} className={`wrapper ${this.props.fade ? 'animation-transition' : ''}`}>
        {/* START OF QUOTE BOX WRAPPER */}
          <div id="quote-box" className="quote-box">
            {/* QUOTE TEXT, ALWAYS UPDATE FROM PROPS PASSED BY PARENT'S STATE */}
            <div className="quote">
              <span style={{'color': this.props.color, 'fill': this.props.color}} id="text" className={`quote-text ${this.props.fade ? 'animation-transition' : ''}`}>{iconQuote} {this.props.quote}</span>
            </div>
            
            {/* AUTHOR TEXT, ALWAYS UPDATE FROM PROPS PASSED BY PARENT'S STATE */}
            <div style={{'color': this.props.color}} id="author" className={`quote-author ${this.props.fade ? 'animation-transition' : ''}`}>
              <span>- {this.props.author}</span>
            </div>
            
            {/* BUTTON WRAPPER */}
            <div className="buttons">
              
              {/* TWITTER BUTTON, UPDATE BACKGROUND FROM PROPS */}
              <a style={{'backgroundColor': this.props.color}} id="tweet-quote" class="tweet-quote-button" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank">
                tweet <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'twitter']} />
              </a>
              
              {/* NEW QUOTE BUTTON, UPDATE BACKGROUND FROM PROPS */}
              <button style={{'backgroundColor': this.props.color}} id="new-quote" className="new-quote-button" onClick={this.props.handleClick} onAnimationEnd={this.props.animationEnd}>new quote</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        {/* END OF QUOTE BOX WRAPPER */}
        
        {/* START OF FOOTER */}
        <div className="footer">
          <span>created by <a href="https://codepen.io/thekevinkun" target="_blank">Kevinkun</a></span>
        </div>
        {/* END OF FOOTER */}
      
      </div>
    )
  }
}
// END OF CHILD COMPONENT //

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I hope you guys want to visit the codepen for better understanding: [My Projects](https://codepen.io/thekevinkun/pen/poWpOyW?editors=0110)

Projects Explanation: Whenever user click new quote button it will do fade-in fade-out transition before displaying the new quote along with new text color and background color.

Problem is: As you can see in my codepen, I don't want the **white box** that wrap all the content follow the animation transition.

This is the example that I want to achieve: [freeCodeCamp Random Quote Machine](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/qRZeGZ)

You can see that in freeCodeCamp example the **white box** didn't do the transitions.

I know this sounds simple, but I'm stuck. I hope you guys understand and write me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `animation-transition` class to `wrapper` div. The example that you are referring is not changing the opacity of the main container but instead changing the rgb values. That why there is a smooth transition of the background color. Whereas you are directly giving the color values with opacity animation hence the entire container is affected. So don't change the opacity of the container.

Comment: So you mean the container background in the projects example doesn't do any of that transitions? It's only changing the rgb values?

Comment: But it seems like the container background also did the transitions. If I only change my container it's rgb value but not include the animation, it won't get the fade-in transitions like in the example